# Same ng-model for input radio and number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my html form I have two different types of input with same `$scope` variable as model.

I have 3 radio buttons and a number input field

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="article.internal_memory" value="16" name="options" id="option1" > 16GB
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="article.internal_memory" value="32" name="options" id="option2" > 32GB
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="article.internal_memory" value="64" name="options" id="option3" > 64GB
    </label>
  </div>
  <input ng-model="article.internal_memory" id="internal-memory-input" placeholder="Outra" type="number" class="form-control">
</div>
```

But if I select one of the radio button inputs, it doesn't set the value.

Having two different inputs for the same scope variable causes conflicts?

Comment: working fine here : https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ttayv25f/2/

Comment: I made a mistake in the html, it's `input="number"` and not `input="text"`

Comment: Did you read console error? It says "Expected `16` to be a number". Your values are strings and can't be shown in the number `input`.

Comment: I don't get that error in my app. That's because it gets the input[radio] value as a string and not a number, as it should

Comment: @tvieira check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)** instead of `value`

Like this

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="article.internal_memory" ng-value="16" name="options" id="option1"> 16GB
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="article.internal_memory" ng-value="32" name="options" id="option2"> 32GB
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="article.internal_memory" ng-value="64" name="options" id="option3"> 64GB
        </label>
      </div>
      <input ng-model="article.internal_memory" id="internal-memory-input" placeholder="Outra" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ttayv25f/3/)**</kbd>